# Magento2. Adding custom attribute category put category name below

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, image, custom-attributes, category-attribute

I successfully added a new image field to category product. This is the category_form.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="product_page_background">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Background Product Page</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">45</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="custom/products/adminhtml/category/productbackground/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

This make the input category name in the background going under the Content Tab:[image]

How can put the category name input back to the top?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with little workaround. Here is my complete `category_form.xml`:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="content">
        <field name="product_page_background">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">category</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Background Product Page</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">45</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="custom/products/adminhtml/category/productbackground/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true"></item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I inserted `<fieldset name="general">` after the declaration of the new field. This makes the general tab to go back to the top of the fieldset.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<fieldset name="content"> to  <fieldset name="general">`

Comment: This restores the general fieldset back to the top but it adds the new field to the general fieldset. I would like to add it in the content tab